# which library should i implement to use app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Tags: android, xml, android-support-library, android-design-library, material-components-android

I want to add the `app:layout_behavior` attribute in xml file but it not supported. Which library should I add in gradle file?

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0
```

when I add this compile library android Studio gives error I have to androidx library to support that `app:layout_behavior`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.expensemanager"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:19.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

please help me what should i implement to support `app:layout_behavior`

Comment: You don't need any extra library

Comment: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) which is a drop-in replacement for Android's Design Support Library.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta02'
```

or the latest stable version:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```